# How to extract src element in a web page in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

i need to extract image src along with name of brand from 'https://www.gizbot.com/mobile-brands-in-india/'.
i have tried doing it using scrapy-
spider.py

```
    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'mobiles-%s.html' % page
        mob = response.xpath('.//div[has-class("all-brands-block-desc-brand")]/text()').getall()
       
        for mobile in mob:
            m = str(mobile).split()[0]
            with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write("%s %s\n" % (mobile, response.xpath('.//a[contains(@href, m)]').xpath("@href").extract()))
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

but it does not extract the right data.I have no idea where am i going wrong.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For extract image src.                                                                                                                                                for i in response.css('div.all-brands-block'):  print("https://www.gizbot.com/" + i.css('img::attr("data-pagespeed-lazy-src")').get())

Answer (score 1):

you need to use following xpath:

```
mob = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "all-brands-block-desc-brand")]').getall()
```

Comment: xpath* 
you have a typo.